# How to whitelist certificate extension in java

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, java-security

While ssl handshake, I get the following error:

```
Certificate contains unsupported critical extensions.
```

This exception is thrown by sun.security.validator.EndEntityChecker class

```
    private void checkRemainingExtensions(Set<String> exts)
            throws CertificateException {
        // basic constraints irrelevant in EE certs
        exts.remove(SimpleValidator.OID_BASIC_CONSTRAINTS);

        // If the subject field contains an empty sequence, the subjectAltName
        // extension MUST be marked critical.
        // We do not check the validity of the critical extension, just mark
        // it recognizable here.
        exts.remove(OID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME);

        if (!exts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CertificateException("Certificate contains unsupported "
                + "critical extensions: " + exts);
        }
    }
```

It turns out that extension, which causes the error is the only one not removed during the validation process.
Removing this extension from CA is not an option.
How can I whitelist this extension?

Comment: An unsupported critical extension is a serious issue. Why does the server certificate have an unsupported/unusual critical extension?

Comment: It is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `PKIXCertPathChecker` that processes and removes this extension, and then add that as a checker using the `PKIXParameters.addCertPathChecker` method, and then set those parameters using the `TrustManagerFactory.init` method.